# Svelte JS - Is it possible to change the global.css build path?

Tags: svelte

I'm developing for a platform that has very specific folder structure requirements. As a result, the global.css file needs to be in a folder (whether that's the build folder or its own) and not the root folder. Is there a way to edit the rollup.config.js so that the global.css file gets relocated to the directory of my choice when I run "npm run build"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using the [Svelte Rollup template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template).

If so, the `global.css` is referenced directly in [index.html](https://github.com/sveltejs/template/blob/8d350b693fb4bd8ecf340841eac22a1cb85d7986/public/index.html#L10).

`index.html`

```html
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/global.css'>
```

Rollup doesn't see nor process this file.

This means you can move it anywhere you want in the `public` directory, as long as you keep the URL in the above line in sync.

I advise against putting it somewhere in the `public/build` directory though, because all the other files in this directory being generated files, this could cause confusion or unnecessary complications.

For example, you can move the file to `public/my-dir/global.css`, and update the link `index.html` accordingly:

`index.html`

```html
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/my-dir/global.css'>
```

---

Another option would be to move the `global.css` file in the `src` directory, and import it in your project, for example in `main.js`:

`main.js`

```js
import './global.css' // we're importing src/global.css
```

This way, `global.css` would get processed by Rollup (thanks to the [CSS plugin](https://github.com/sveltejs/template/blob/8d350b693fb4bd8ecf340841eac22a1cb85d7986/rollup.config.js#L48) in the config), and its content will end up in the `bundle.css` file of the build.

Comment: Talk about a simple solution to a problem that I WAY overthought...  Thank you sincerely for taking the time to patiently explain this in such detail.  It worked a charm!